# Send Firebase Cloud Messages using HTTP protocol

Tags: android, ios, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to build a chat app for Android, iOS and web using FCM. I want my messages to be stored in my server so my idea is sending messages from my app to my server and then from my server to others app user using firebase. I've discovered this method (https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref) to send messages, but my question is, would messages be delivered to my apps using xmpp? will be there any extra delay to deliver messages? I may have chats around 50 participant, will it be a problem?

Comment: It won't be a problem even you have thousands of participants or millions and you don't have to do anything extra like implementing xmpp or any other protocol firebase and google do manage this.

Comment: There will be no delay. There are two protocols you can use: HTTP or XMPP

Answer (score -1):

You can send message with curl in PHP

```
function sendGCM($message, $id) {


    $url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';

    $fields = array (
            'registration_ids' => array (
                    $id
            ),
            'data' => array (
                    "message" => $message
            )
    );
    $fields = json_encode ( $fields );

    $headers = array (
            'Authorization: key=' . "YOUR_KEY_HERE",
            'Content-Type: application/json'
    );

    $ch = curl_init ();
    curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
    curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, true );
    curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
    curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
    curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields );

    $result = curl_exec ( $ch );
    echo $result;
    curl_close ( $ch );
}

?>
```

$message is your message to send to the device

$id is the devices registration token

YOUR_KEY_HERE is your Server API Key (or Legacy Server API Key)